# What is the best way of checking HTTP resources with Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to check if several HTTP resources exist on the server and when they don't I would like to upload them. The problem is I am not sure how to register multiple

```
- name: Checking if schema already exists
  uri:
    url: http://{{ riak_server }}:10018/search/schema/{{ item }} return_content=yes
  register: http_response_{{ item }}
  failed_when: http_response_{{ item }}.status != 400
  with_items:
    - sch_patents
    - sch_entities
    - sch_cpcs
    - sch_ipcs
    - sch_entities_patents
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: "{{ riak_server }}"
  tags: creating_schema
```

Invoking the task fails:

```
TASK: [riak | Checking if schema already exists] ******************************
fatal: [10.10.10.11 -> 10.10.10.11] => error while evaluating conditional: http_response_sch_patents.status != 400

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

What is the right approach of checking several resources and upload the ones missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When registering the output from a looped task (such as when using `with_items`) you will get a dict of responses back from all of the looped variables.

So instead you should be doing something like this:

```
- name: Checking if schema already exists
  uri:
    url: http://{{ riak_server }}:10018/search/schema/{{ item }} return_content=yes
  register: http_responses
  with_items:
    - sch_patents
    - sch_entities
    - sch_cpcs
    - sch_ipcs
    - sch_entities_patents
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: "{{ riak_server }}"
  tags: creating_schema

- name: copy schema if not exists
  copy:
    src: path/to/src/schema
    dest: path/to/dest/
  when: {{ item.status }} != 400
  with_items: http_responses.results
```